# GET 404 Error When Trying to Load a functions.js File Inside an html File in Browser (*using node js as server)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I'm trying to make my code more easy to navigate, by separating all my functions from the html page, to have them in their own js file,
in the html file I simply have

```
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

inside the `<head></head>` tags

checking the console in the browser, I see a GET error 404 `http://localhost:5000/functions.js`
adding

```
app.get('/functions.js', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/functions.js'));
})
```

does not solve it (note that the same command, but with '/index.html' loads the main html file just fine)

How can I properly utilize the bulk of my functions inside the main  tag in the html page, while having all the declarations and definitions inside a separate .js file?

**all files are in the same folder**

**added solution as answer**

Comment: If you find a solution, it is generally better to post it as an answer rather than to edit your post, in a few days you will be able to mark your own answer as a solution too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently I needed to have a server-side app.get command for the functions.js file

```
app.get('/functions.js', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/functions.js'));
})
```